# C# and WinForms как вернуть исходное состояние формы?

Tags: c#

У формы исходное состояние вот такой
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

когда заполняю `textbox`-и потом нажатием `button` сохраняю данные и в месте с этим работает

```
foreach (Control tb in this.Controls)
{
    if (tb is TextBox)
    {
        ((TextBox)tb).Clear();
    }
    else if (tb is MaskedTextBox)
    {
        ((MaskedTextBox)tb).Clear();
    }
}
```

вот такой код все эти три `textbox`-и у которых по умолчанию задана `0` это значение удаляется и получает значение `null`,как написать код чистки что бы форма вернулась в исходное состояние  ??

Comment: Вардан, ну вы бы научились форматировать код. Не первый же день на сайте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, вы можете положить исходное значение для каждого контрола в его [`Tag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), и копировать оттуда при восстановлении.